# Combine Output of Queries in Pivot Table with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, datatable, count, pivot

Suppose I have a table called orders that looks like this:

| id | order date | Orders_Wanted | Orders_Given |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-11-29 19:12:44.417 | 2 | 6 |
| 1 | 2020-11-29 20:12:44.417 | 2 | 6 |
| 1 | 2020-11-30 23:37:28.692 | 8 | 2 |
| 1 | 2020-11-30 23:37:28.692 | 2 | 6 |

How do I write a query that shows the count of orders_wanted - orders_given by hour broken down into two columns, one that counts positive results and one that counts negative results (a note that orders_wanted and orders_given are times, so that's why I am calculating orders_wanted - orders_given). I would also like to add a final column that calculates the percentage of total orders per hour that are positive (count_orders_positive/ (count_orders_negative + Count_orders_positive)).

The output of the query would look something like this:

| week | day | hour | count_orders_positive | count_orders_negative | Percentage_orders_positive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 48 | 7 | 19 | 0 | 1 | 100% |
| 48 | 7 | 20 | 0 | 1 | 100% |
| 49 | 1 | 23 | 1 | 1 | 50% |

So far I am able to get the bottom two results using these queries, but I don't know how to combine them.

```
SELECT  
extract (week from (order_date at time zone 'MST' at time zone 'UTC') ) as "week", 
extract (isodow from (order_date at time zone 'MST' at time zone 'UTC') ) as "day",
extract (hour from (order_date at time zone 'MST' at time zone 'UTC') ) as "hour",
Count (extract (hour from (order_date at time zone 'MST' at time zone 'UTC') )) as 
"count_orders_positive" 
from orders  
WHERE orders_wanted - orders_given >= 0
group by week, day, hour
order by week, day, hour;
```

| week | day | hour | count_orders_positive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 49 | 1 | 23 | 1 |

```
SELECT
extract (week from (order_date at time zone 'MST' at time zone 'UTC') ) as "week", 
extract (isodow from (order_date at time zone 'MST' at time zone 'UTC') ) as "day",
extract (hour from (order_date at time zone 'MST' at time zone 'UTC') ) as "hour",
Count (extract (hour from (order_date at time zone 'MST' at time zone 'UTC') )) as 
"count_orders_negative" 
from orders  
WHERE orders_wanted - orders_given < 0
group by week, day, hour
order by week, day, hour;
```

| week | day | hour | count_orders_negative |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 48 | 7 | 19 | 1 |
| 48 | 7 | 20 | 1 |
| 49 | 1 | 23 | 1 |

Comment: How do you get `count_positive == 1` from `wanted == 2` and `given == 6`

Comment: @s-man Thank you for pointing that out. I made a mistake with my example tables. I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation. `avg()` comes handy to compute the percentage:

```
select  
    extract (week   from (order_date at time zone 'MST' at time zone 'UTC') ) as "week", 
    extract (isodow from (order_date at time zone 'MST' at time zone 'UTC') ) as "day",
    extract (hour   from (order_date at time zone 'MST' at time zone 'UTC') ) as "hour",
    count(*) filter (where orders_wanted - orders_given >= 0) as count_orders_positive,
    count(*) filter (where orders_wanted - orders_given <  0) as count_orders_negative,
    100 * avg((orders_wanted - orders_given >= 0)::int) as percent_orders_positive
from orders
group by week, day, hour
order by week, day, hour;
```